# how to save response data inside a JSONModel in SAPUI5?

Tags: javascript, json, sapui5

In my code I have to make a call filtered on two properties (anno and mese) to the Timesheet entity and then I have to expand to its other entities which are 'stato' and 'righe'.

The response then I will have to save it in a JSON model that I will use for the Binding in the View.

I made the code below but something is wrong because it gives an error on `getProperty`:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getProperty') at f.loadTimesheet (Home.controller.js:41:39) at f.onInit (Home.controller.js:24:22)...

(I'm doing something wrong but I don't know what because I'm new and inexperienced)

```
    onInit: function () {

            // 
            var oModel = new JSONModel()
            this.getView().setModel(oModel, "timesheetModel")
            
            this.loadTimesheet();


        },
      


        loadTimesheet: function (oEvent) {
            var oView = this.getView()
            var oModel = oView.getModel("timesheetModel")

            var service = "http://localhost:4004/v2/odata/v4"//url del mio servizio Odata
            var oTimesheet = oView.getModel("Timesheet")
            // var oTimesheet = new ODataModel("http://localhost:4004/v2/odata/v4")
            // this.getView().setModel(oTimesheet, "Timesheet")
            var anno = oTimesheet.getProperty("/Anno")
            var mese = oTimesheet.getProperty("/Mese")

            var oDataModel = new ODataModel(service)
            this.getView().setModel(oDataModel)

            oTimesheet.read("/Timesheet", {
                filters: [
                    new Filter("Anno", FilterOperator.EQ, anno),
                    new Filter("Mese", FilterOperator.EQ, mese),
                ],

                urlParameters: {
                    "$expand": "stato,righe"
                },
                success: function (oData) {
                    var oModel = this.getView().getModel("timesheetModel")
                    oModel.setData(oData)

                }.bind(this),
                error: function (err) {
                    console.error(err)
                }
            })



        }
```

Comment: What error message? Which `getProperty` line?

Comment: Yes, the error is -> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getProperty')
    at f.loadTimesheet (Home.controller.js:41:39)
    at f.onInit (Home.controller.js:24:22)...

Comment: I have updated your question with your comment. On which line does it happen?

Comment: var oTimesheet = oView.getModel("Timesheet") 

Where did you set the model "Timesheet" ?